# I have no idea how to test this with Qunit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I want to test this function:
/js/lib/front.js

```
var Front = function(){
  this.onSignUp = function(){
    if (!Form.assertInput("email")) {
        $("input[name=email]").focus();

        this.showHiddenMessage("Email not set.");

        return false;
    }
 }
```

}

I have in:
/js/lib/form.js

```
function Form() {
     this.assertInput = function (name, defaultValue) {
    var text = $("input[name=" + name + "]").val();

    if (defaultValue != null) {
        if (defaultValue && text == defaultValue) 
            return false;
    }


    if(this.trim(text)) return true;

    return false;
}
}
```

This simple test passing:

```
test("Front", function() {
    var front = new Front()
    ok(front);

 });
```

But if I write something like this:

```
test("On Sign Up ", function() {
    var front = new Front()

    equal(front.onSignUp(),false,"passing test");

 });
```

I have error:
Died on test #1: Form.assertInput is not a function

I don't understand, what I need test in function like this and how include function inside another function?

Comment: What are the `this`es referring to in the different files? Are you sure you don't perhaps need `this.assertInput("email")`?

Comment: Is `Form` an instance or a static reference in the first code block?

Comment: I have: function Form(){this.assertInput = function(name,defaultValue){....}}

Answer (score 2):

I've saved a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/smXMx/). As a side note, you might want to check out a tutorial on using qUnit, [here](http://www.swift-lizard.com/2009/11/24/test-driven-development-with-jquery-qunit/).One thing that you need to pay attention to is when you're declaring your functions. It's saying `Form.assertInput` is not a function because you can't access it like that. You need to use the `this` keyword, which refers to current context. The code should be something like this:

```
var Form = function () {
    //good to have assertInput first if you're using it in a later function
    this.assertInput = function (name, defaultValue) {
        var text = $("input[name=" + name + "]").val();

        if (defaultValue != null) {
            //safer to explicitly close your if statements with {}
            if (defaultValue && text == defaultValue) {
               return false;
            }
        }

        if ($.trim(text)) { return true; }

        return false;
    };

    this.showHiddenMessage = function (message) {
        alert(message);
    };

    this.onSignUp = function() {
        //this will point to the current context, in this case it will be Form class
        if (!this.assertInput("email")) {
            $("input[name=email]").focus();

            this.showHiddenMessage("Email not set.");

            return false;
        }
    };
};
```

Also in the example code that you gave you're missing the `Front` class. So I created a dummy one in my fiddle like this:

```
var Front = function() {};
```

Here are the tests that were run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    test("Front", function() {
        var front = new Front();
        ok(front);

    });
    test("On Sign Up ", function() {
       var form = new Form();
       equal(form.onSignUp(), false, "passing test");
    });
});
```